# Get Input tag Attribute ID name at Runtime in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I need to **get input tag Attribute ID name** at run time in Meteor js. I was developed one sample example as shown below.

```
HTML code :

<body>

  {{>ui}}<br>
</body>

<template name="ui">
<input type="button" value="" id="btn1"/>
<input type="button" value="" id="btn2"/>
</template>

JS Code :

Template.ui.events
({
    'click input' : function (event)
    {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
         //get input tag Attribute ID name here
        console.log("Get input button id here");
    }
  });
```

I am new to Meteor, I don't have any idea about this so please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With plain JS you can write :

```
event.currentTarget.id
```

With jQuery :

```
$(event.currentTarget).attr("id")
```